# regExp to find a url pattern from a text area content

Tags: regex, extjs

i am working with ext js 4. I have a text area field,in which i could type in a maximum of 160 characters.I want to check whether a url is present in the content.If yes then i want to subtract the length of that url from the entire content length.
The only validation required for the url is it should start with 'http://'.

The text area contains some normal text plus additional url. The url can be placed anywhere in the content. i want to find a pattern matching for the url from the text area content

Answer (score 0):

You can match the url with this:

```
/(http:\/\/\S+)/
```

You can then check the length of the matched group to find out how much to subtract.

I don't know what you need this for, but be aware that this can easily be used to spam your input data.

Example:

> I'm writing normal text, and I'm limited to 160 characters.
>
> http://but.if.I.write.like.this.I.can.type.as.much.as.I.want.